# The metric coefficients in cylindrical coordinates are (a) $(1,1,1)$ (b) $(1,0,1)$ (c) $(1,r,1)$ (d) neither?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-analysis, differential, general-relativity

In Differential and Riemannian Geometry we study metric cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, z).$  I am preparing its Multiple choice questions,

Q. The metric coefficients in cylindrical coordinates are

(a) $(1,1,1)$   (b) $(1,0,1)$  (c) $(1,r,1)$   (d) neither

Can anyone explain,
what are metric coefficients in general?

what is relationship between metric tensor and metric coefficient?

How is it related to $ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+dz^2$? From here i am guessing the answer (1, r^2, 1) am I right?? Thanks

Comment: Metric coefficients are the elements of the tensor. It's a list because many common metric tensors are diagonal

Comment: can we say that metric coeeficients are ddiagonal of metric tensor?? or the metric coefficients are non zero elements of a metric tensor?

Comment: In other words your guess for the answer I'm 80% sure is correct. The uncertainty comes from teachers and textbooks being unclear with their notation and vocabulary.